# Maven deployment with Cargo plugin - Invalid property for deployable

Tags: maven, deployment, continuous-integration, cargo

The deployment to the Glassfish server fails because the Cargo plugin has an invalid property. 
I have a multi module Maven project with this parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.skb</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectMonkeybutler</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>ProjectMonkeybutler</name>

<modules>
    <module>ProjectMonkeybutler-ear</module>
    <module>ProjectMonkeybutler-web</module>
    <module>ProjectMonkeybutler-ejb</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<repositories>  
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>  
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
        <layout>default</layout>  
    </repository>  
</repositories>
```

I would like to execute an auto redeployment to my Glassfish server but this is not possible from the parent pom because it is not a war/ear file which will be produced. I integrated the Cargo plugin into the ear project but the deployment is not successful.

My pom.xml for the ear project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" x  mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<artifactId>ProjectMonkeybutler</artifactId>
<groupId>com.skb</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.skb.monkeybutler.ear</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectMonkeybutler-ear</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<name>ProjectMonkeybutler-ear</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.hostname>localhost</cargo.hostname>
                        <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                        <cargo.remote.password>password</cargo.remote.password>
                        <cargo.remote.port>50447</cargo.remote.port>
                        <cargo.glassfish.domain.name>/domain1</cargo.glassfish.domain.name>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <type>ear</type>
                        <properties>
                            <context>/monkeybutler-dev</context>
                        </properties>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.deployment</groupId>
                    <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2-b06</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.skb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectMonkeybutler-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.skb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectMonkeybutler-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The error after

```
mvn cargo:deploy

ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.7:redeploy (default-cli) on project ProjectMonkeybutler-ear: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.7:redeploy failed: Invalid property [context] for deployable type [ear]: org.codehaus.cargo.container.deployable.EAR.setContext([Ljava.lang.String;) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context property is only allowed for WARs.

See the column `Deployable Type` in the documentation: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide#Maven2PluginReferenceGuide-prop2